# Как показать ближайший понедельник?

Tags: дата, php

Мне нужно показать ближайший понедельник и число, но если до него 3 или менее дней, то показывать следующий понедельник и число месяца.

Например сегодня пятница 4 июля, следующий понедельник, 7 июля, но я буду показывать 14 июля, т.к до 7 июля уже 3 дня осталось.

Comment: @Tchort Покажите что уже готово, иначе это работа за автора

Comment: А http://us1.php.net/manual/ru/function.mktime.php, http://us1.php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php и http://us1.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php, не?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Магия! Магия!

```
$date = new \DateTime('next monday');
```

Comment: проверил, [работает](http://ideone.com/GagkV5)!

Comment: @sergiks, а чего б ему не работать? )) Я бы только временную зону добавил, на всякий пожарный.

    $date = new \DateTime('next monday',new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow'));

Comment: @Deonis, никогда не пользовался в таком виде, поражён семантикой!

    new DateTime('the day I tried to live'); // youtu.be/dbckIuT_YDc

Comment: @Deonis никогда не хардкодьте таймзону.